# A garbled copy of MY blog on this site?

Tags: blog

I stumbled upon a website that had a garbled copy of a post I wrote a while ago and posted somewhere else.  This site has no contact, no way to get in touch with admin, just brings me to wordpress.org....which is why I'm asking here.  I have no idea what to do...obviously this site is not legit..it seems all the posts (blogs) are stolen from other bloggers.  And why is it so garbled, as if translated from another language??  Can anybody help me?  I need to remove my post from there and have no way to do it.  Here is the website and the link to my original post and the link to the garbled one I found.

http://activerain.com/blogsview/2078742/the-art-of-hanging-art           http://cgcaf.com/tag/hanging-art-on-the-wall

CGCAF.com is the website.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a **legal** issue, not a WordPress one. Please explore your legal options, which depends a lot on countries of parties (you, owner of that site, hosting) and more.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like they're trying to content farm for SEO purposes without getting hit by duplicate content penalties. The first thing I would do would be to get in touch with [their hosting](http://www.whoishostingthis.com/cgcaf.com), since the domain is registered to someone in Indonesia and calling would probably not get you the results you're looking for. Talk to their host, explain what's up, and see if you can get anything resolved that way. If not, you can try getting in touch with google and bing and see about getting them pulled from the rankings, essentially causing the site to cease to exist as far as the internet is concerned. At the end of the day, there's not much you can do to directly force them to take your content down (as far as I'm aware) without going through a whole bunch of legal mess.